# render failing in rspec test for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, bdd

In my view spec i have the following

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "my_project/index.html.erb" do
  it "displays the Country drop down" do
    render
    rendered.should contain("Country")
  end
end
```

But when i run the spec im getting the following error

```
Failure/Error: render
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

Im confused as to why am i getting this error when my page does actually contain the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need an instance variable for it to work with? I.e what ever is set up in the controller index method... So something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "my_project/index.html.erb" do
  before do
    @some_instance_variable = SomeClass.all
    render
  end

  it "displays the Country drop down" do
    rendered.should contain("Country")
  end
end
```